# How I can connect emulator into vscode to make a flutter projects

Tags: flutter

I installed vscode and emulator but the emulator doesn't work in vscode .how I can skip this problem

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, post your code/ log error or some evidences that let us to help you.

Comment: Can you please paste the code after running `Flutter doctor` inside your project? Your devices might not have the developer options enabled and therefore Flutter can't see them.